SentenceTransformerEmbeddings without installing sentence transformers
I had my langchain project working on my win10 laptop, but after moving it to Debian GNU/Linux 12 server, I've learned that I can't install sentence transformers (python 3.11) in realation to problems with installing torch.
Is there some alternative to SentenceTransformerEmbeddings without  sentence transformers?
I tried installing torch from https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html but it told me it doesn't have a matching version.

What version of Python are you running?

@James Python 3.11.2

This sounds like an X-Y problem.  Why is Torch not installable?

Had 32 bit system installed by mistake. Server reinstalation fixed the problem.
